# Two listview builders in a parent listview but not rendering. Only the visibles instead rendering all at once

Tags: android, flutter, listview, scroll

```
 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return Scaffold(
     body: ListView(
       children: <Widget>[
         _firstListView(),
         _secondListView(),
      ],
    ),
  );
}
```

Main class that calls other **listView** builders

```
Widget _firstListView() {
return Container(
  color: Colors.green,
  child: ListView.builder(
    itemCount: 200,
    shrinkWrap: true,
    physics: const ClampingScrollPhysics(),
    itemBuilder: (context, index) => RecCell(
      index: index,
    ),
  ),
);
}
```

first listView builder

```
Widget _secondListView() {
return Container(
  color: Colors.red,
  child: ListView.builder(
    itemCount: 200,
    shrinkWrap: true,
    physics: const ClampingScrollPhysics(),
    itemBuilder: (context, index) => ListTile(title: Text("Second $index")),
  ),
);
 }
```

the second **listView** builder

**RecCell** is another statefull widget that prints in init method when the widget is build and it build 200 times on restart and never recreated on scrolling

I want them to reuse each time parent listview scrolls any help will appreciated..

**EDIT 27 APRIL 2023**

Use Custom scroll view to do weird or complex scrolling

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did this and worked for me

```
Map<String, dynamic> d = {
   0:..,listView widget,
   1:[...list of widgets]
}
```

I am making a map containing all my widgets, and in the build method I am returning a listview with those widgets

```
return ListView(
  children:[
     d[0],
     ...d[1] // this will extract each widget from the list and insert it to list view
  ]
)
```

In this way my d[0] is horizontal listview builder and d[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ixZdY.png) are other  widget that I am adding into parent list view directly now they all are rerendering when visible. Had to do some changing in my previous code

Final output:

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ixZdY.png)

Answer (score 1):

Well, wrapping them in a `ListView` removes the lazy loading benefit of `ListView.builder`, because the outer `ListView` wants to load all children at once. I think the best way is the combine the data of the two `ListView.builders` into a single one. Although, wrapping them in a colored container would not be possible then, but maybe you get the desired result by wrapping the items in it. So something like:

```
Widget builds(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
      body: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: 400,
          shrinkWrap: true,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) => index < 200
              ? Container(
                  color: Colors.green,
                  child: RecCell(
                    index: index,
                  ),
                )
              : Container(
                  color: Colors.red,
                  child: ListTile(title: Text("Second ${index - 200}")))));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `NestedScrollView` if you have nested listview in the body of the parent widget.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
   body: ListView(
     children: <Widget>[
       Container(height: 300, child: _firstListView()),
       Container(height: 300, child: _secondListView()),
     ],
   ),
 );
}
```

-----------OR------------

```
 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 return Scaffold(
   body: SingleChildScrollView(
     children: <Widget>[
       Container(height: 300, child: _firstListView()),
       Container(height: 300, child: _secondListView()),
     ],
   ),
 );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use CustomScrollView instead ListViews for this case

```
CustomScrollView(
  slivers: [
    SliverList(
      delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
        (context, index) => Container(),
      ),
    ),
    SliverList(
      delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
        (context, index) => Container(),
      ),
    ),
  ],
);
```

because the ListView requires all available space and expands its own size as much as possible to understand how many child elements can be displayed